# How to avoid cache issue between switching web application versions when using the SmartGwt ListGrid Offline storage?

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am new to smart GWT. With the help of the **listGrid unique id** I am storing the state of the listGrid in the **offline storage**. I am using the package `com.smartgwt.client.util.Offline` to store the state of the listGrid. Now after storing the state of the listGrid in `version1` of my software, when I upload a new version which is`version2`,some how the listGrid state was not changing. It was using the state of version1 though I have uploaded a new version2 with new compiled smart GWT modules. But, when I clear the browser cache I am able to get the new state of the ListGrid. My questions is:

Is there any way to get the new state of the ListGrid without clearing the browser cache when I upload a new version?

please check the sample code form the below

```
public abstract class WebUIListGrid extends ListGrid {
    protected GroupTypeInfo groupTypeInfo;
    public final FieldNames fieldNames = FieldNames.getInstance();
    public ResourceString resourceString = null;

    // Constructor of the WebUIListGrid
    public WebUIListGrid(GroupTypeInfo groupTypeInfo) {
        resourceString = ResourceString.getInstance();
        this.groupTypeInfo = groupTypeInfo;
        this.groupId = groupTypeInfo.getGroupId();
        setListGridProperties();
    }

    /**
     * set basic properties
     */              
    private void setListGridProperties() {
       // This Id is used for the offline storage
        setID(getListGridId() + groupId);
        addListGridField();
        // Code to add the dataSorce
        addDS();
        // This will apply the state of the field using the offline storage
        applyFieldState();
    }

    /**
     * store list grid column fields in off line     
     */
    public void storeFieldState(){
        // Here I am storing the state of the listGrid.
        Offline.put(getListGridId(), getViewState());
    }


    /**
     * apply list grid column state
     */
    public void applyFieldState(){
        try{
            final String viewState = (String) Offline.get(getId());
            if (viewState != null) {
                addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler() {  

                    @Override  
                    public void onDraw(DrawEvent event) {  
                        //restore any previously saved view state for this grid  
                        setViewState(viewState);  
                    }  
                }); 
            }
         } catch(Exception e) {

         } 
        FieldStateChangedHandler fieldStateChangedHandler = new FieldStateChangedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFieldStateChanged(FieldStateChangedEvent event) {
                            Offline.put(getId(), getViewState());
                            updateFieldChangeCallBack();
            }
        };
        addFieldStateChangedHandler(fieldStateChangedHandler);
    }

    /*
     * The id of the offline storage
    */
    private String getId(){
        return LoginInfo.getLoginId()+"_"+getListGridId();
    }

}
```

Any Suggestions would be appreciated.